# Getting a syntax error when used const { icon, ...other } = this.props;

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using latest react and started a new project 
my code is like this

```
 export default class MaterialIcon extends Component {
   render() {
     const {  icon, ...other } = this.props;

     return (
      <MaterialIconDefault
        icon={icon}
        {...other}
      />
}
}
```

Can anyone say what went wrong

Comment: Replace `const {  icon, ...other } = this.props;` this with `const {  icon, other } = this.props;` You are using spread operator '...'  while getting values form props so you can not use `{...other}` in return. That's why you need to do just `const {  icon, other } = this.props;` in declaration.

Comment: by doing i may not be able to send the ...other  props in return block to MaterialIconDefault

Comment: if you replace `const {  icon, ...other } = this.props;` with `const {  icon, other } = this.props;` then you can pass on the `others` using spread operator to `MaterialIconDefault`.

Comment: I have installed babel-stage-3 and included it to .babelrc file It worked .Thanks you very much for your response